# CSS3 Keyframes animation not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make css3 slider when i set -moz- prefix for image sliding slider even not work in chrome let alone Mozilla Firefox. but =webkit- prefix is working good in Chrome if i do not use -moz prefix with -webkit. even i declare caption animation. Caption animation is not working.

just have look on my code : http://codepen.io/faeshaan/pen/pefwq

Comment: try this?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AjoHm

Answer (score 1):

I found a few issues looking at you code:

- [syntax for keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) should be `@keframes slide{}` not `@keyframes 'slide' {}`
- the slide animation was missing a closing `}`
- added an initial `left:0;` position to `.container ul` as [dc5 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17844396/1947286)
- added a specific height of 200px to `.container` to make the heading animation look a little cleaner.

This will work as is in Firefox v22, but you will still need to add browser prefixes for full support.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Kcjud/4/)**

```
.container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container ul {
    width:1000px;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    animation: slide 20s infinite;
}
ul, li {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.container ul li {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    float:left;
}
.container h5 {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    animation: headings 4s infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
    10% {
        left:0px;
    }
    15%, 30% {
        left:-200px;
    }
    35%, 50% {
        left:-400px;
    }
    55%, 70% {
        left:-600px;
    }
    75%, 90% {
        left:-800px;
    }
}
@keyframes headings {
    10% {
        margin-bottom:4px;
    }
    25%, 50% {
        margin-bottom:-150px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding in the keyframe definitions and css properties for mozilla (basically what @Ilan Biala said re: css markup) the animation still didn't work for me on OSX Firefox v22.

Adding an initial:

```
left: 0px;
```

Made the animation start working.  Seems firefox didn't like animating left unless it was first explicitly defined in the css class.

Comment: Works great and I used this fix for both FF and IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged your code to put the keyframe animation definitions below the properties that are using them. Also, you only had the `-webkit-animation: ;` declaration, so I added the other declarations for mozilla, microsoft, opera, and W3C compliant browsers.

I also combined the `animation-iteration-count: ;` into the `animation: ;` declaration because it saves a little text in the file.

So now instead of what you had before:

```
.container h5 {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    -webkit-animation: headings 20s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes headings {
  10%  {
     margin-bottom:4px;
  }
  15%,30% {
     margin-bottom:-200px;
  }
}
```

It looks like this:

```
.container h5 {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:4px;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    -webkit-animation: headings 20s;
    -moz-animation: headings 20s;
    -ms-animation: headings 20s;
    -o-animation: headings 20s;
    animation: headings 20s;
}
```

And I added the corresponding keyframe definitions.

The final pen is [here](http://codepen.io/nbatothemax/pen/mrLws).